# Flutter: how do I make Google Sign in Permissions mandatory?

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I am using GoogleSignIn in Flutter. How do I make the fourth permission in the picture mandatory, just like the other three? I am using the following code.

```
import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as ga;
final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn.standard(scopes: [ga.DriveApi.driveAppdataScope]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Google announced in 2018 that its OAuth offering will require developers to support granular permissions: https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/more-granular-google-account.html.

You cannot make this permission mandatory. You can however, use incremental auth, where you ask the user to Sign In with Google first and then ask for drive permissions in the context of some additional feature you are offering to your users. Here is more documentation for incremental auth: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#incrementalAuth.